# jQuery: Selecting an element in inside an already selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

For example:

```
$("table tr").click( function(event)
{
   //Say, here i want get the data of td element where its class name="special"
});
```

Is there any way I can select a element while in the click event, a element under the attached element above `$("table tr")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this specific case, you can do this:

```
$("table tr").click( function(event)
{
   $(this).children('td.special').whatEverYouNeed();
});
```

Generally speaking, you need to use `find()`:

```
$("table tr").click( function(event)
{
   $(this).find('td.special').whatEverYouNeed();
});
```

Comment: You can also use `$('td.special', this)` - that will limit the scope of the selector to the container `this`

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
$(this).find(".special").html();
```

I think that that works