# How do I select a sub element when I have selected the root using an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to bind to an element using jQuery and instead of...

```
jQuery('#' + obj.id)
```

I want to use...

```
jQuery(obj)
```

However then I need to get to a div nested within this element so what I want it something like...

```
jQuery(obj + 'div').doSomething()....
```

But that doesnt work. How do I sub select elements after selecting an element using the object directly?

p.s. (there is no id on the obj element (it doesnt exist)...

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Selecting an element in inside an already selected element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629730/jquery-selecting-an-element-in-inside-an-already-selected-element)

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
jQuery(obj).find('div')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("div", obj)
```

Or

```
jQuery(obj).find("div")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
jQuery('div', obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to search for descendant elements:

```
$(obj).find('div')
```