# Setting select index

Tags: jquery

I know I can select an option in a select box by doing

```
$('#selectBox :nth-child(4)').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

But how can I do this through a returned jQuery object? e.g. something like

```
var box = $('#selectBox');
$(box  :nth-child(4)').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Selecting an element in inside an already selected element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629730/jquery-selecting-an-element-in-inside-an-already-selected-element)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/):

```
box.children(':nth-child(4)').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

BTW, starting from jQuery 1.6 you can use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr`:

```
box.children(':nth-child(4)').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: re: `.prop` vs `.attr` - `s/can/should/`

Comment: @Alnitak I'd also prefer `prop` but who knows what is better for the OP.

Comment: If he's on 1.6+ then IMHO `.prop` is always "better"

Comment: @Alnitak Maybe he is obsessed with backwards compatibility :)

Comment: Yep using 1.6+, nope not obsessed with backward compatability ;), yep using prop and yep happy with your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use selector with context like:

```
$(':nth-child(4)', box).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

***PS:*** you could just use `.val()` method if you know the option value.

```
$('#selectBox').val(the_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
box.find(':nth-child(4)')[0].selected = true;
```

Comment: Do you mean `prop("selected", true)`?

Comment: @VisioN no, but I did mean to extract the DOM node, which your comment reminded me to fix :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for that.

```
var box = $('#selectBox');
box.children(':nth-child(4)').prop('selected', 'selected');
```